# Populating the data from JavaScript to textBox

Tags: javascript

I have a text box where i need to load the  data when form is loaded. In "G6data" variable i am getting the value 100 but it is not getting populated in G6 text box.
How can i populate the data which i got into input box using getElementByID.
Please help

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body onload="myFunction()">        
        <input type="text" id="f6" value="5000" />
        <input type="text" id="G6" value="" />
        <button >Try it</button>        
        <script>
        function myFunction()
        {
        var F6=document.getElementById("F6").value;
           var as6=calculateAS6(F6);    
           var as4=CalculateAS4(as6);
           var G6data=AveragePercentage(as6,as4);
document.getElementById("G6").innerHTML=G6data;       
        }
        </script>       
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistake in Input element and for give value to any text box we use `.value` insted of `.innerHTML`.

Use this code

```
     <html>
        <body onload="myFunction()">        
         <input type="text" id="f6" value="5000" />
         <input type="text" id="G6" value="" />
         <button >Try it</button>        
        <script>
        function myFunction()
        {
        var F6=document.getElementById("f6").value;
           var as6=calculateAS6(F6);    
           var as4=CalculateAS4(as6);
           var G6data=AveragePercentage(as6,as4);
        document.getElementById("G6").value=G6data;       
        }
        </script>       
        </body>

      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `value`

```
document.getElementById("G6").value=G6data;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple problem here

```
<input type="text" id="f6" value="5000" />
```

Your id here is 'f6' while you are trying to fetch element with an id of 'F6' here

```
var F6=document.getElementById("F6").value;
```

and use value instead of innerHTML here

```
document.getElementById("G6").innerHTML=G6data;
```